# Android Route Overlay

Tags: android, gps, overlay

First, sorry for my bad English.

My question should be quite simple I think, but I didn't find an understandable example on google.

I'm working on an Android app, which can display a route of several gps points.

I've succeeded with displaying a start and endneedle on the google maps map.

Now I would like to show the route as a line between the individual points as well and thats the point where I don't know how to do it.

I would be really happy if someone could show me a simple example of how I can create line Overlays in Google Maps.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-12-15-n14.html) for you.

Take a look ,I think this will help you.